# Strange behaviour of mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I Have two types of queries

1. ID IN ('123456',1234456)
2. ID IN ('123456','1234456')

Strange issue is when i used mysql explain query 1st query is not using index on ID while second query is using index.

I am really confused why ?

ID IS unique key (int)

Comment: if ID is an int, why do you encapsulate the values to look for in quotes, suggesting they might be strings?

Comment: Don't use strings for numbers and don't use numbers for string: `'123456'` is a string, `123456` is a number.

Comment: @fvu still not sure of the behaviour

Comment: You probably confused the optimizer - just stick to the proper syntax, that will make both your and the optimizer's life a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never mix quoted and unquoted values in an IN list because the comparison rules for quoted values (such as strings) and unquoted values (such as numbers) differ. Mixing types may therefore lead to inconsistent results.

For example, do not write an IN expression like this:

```
SELECT val1 FROM tbl1 WHERE val1 IN (1,2,'a');
```

Instead, write it like this:

```
SELECT val1 FROM tbl1 WHERE val1 IN ('1','2','a');
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is apparently not able to use the index if the `IN` list contains a mixture of different datatypes. In your case, you mix strings and integers.

Comment: @KrishR gave the documentation link.